# How to encode 4B/5B

Tags: protocol-theory, layer1

In encoding 4B5B, the rule  is no more than one leading zero and no more than two trailing zeros. For example, to convert `1110`, the result is  `11100`; just add zero to end.

To convert `0101`, I thought the result should be `01010` because only one leading zero and no more than two trailing zeros.

However, the correct result is `01011`. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nibble `0101` can't be converted to `01010` because that's what `0100` converts to. Before you ask why `0100` doesn't convert to `01001`, it's because `0001` converts to `01001`.

The nibbles are converted from a dictionary, and the dictionary specifies that `0101` converts to `01011`. Encoding and decoding by a dictionary is fast and easy, which is appealing when designing communications systems.

Comment: so, how did the dictionary get created?